# How can I simplify my code in Flask and html

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been doing flask and python for about 3 weeks now.

I am trying to make a form and table that takes two currencies and the exchange rate and finds both sides of the exchange.

i.e CAD to US and US to CAD

This is the relevant piece of code in my app.py:

```
    @app.route("/form", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def forms():
        global reverse_exchange_rate, exchange_rate
        form = CurrencyForm
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template("form.html")

        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
            currency_1 = request.form['currency_1']
            currency_2 = request.form['currency_2']
            exchange_rate = float(request.form['exchange_rate'])
            reverse_exchange_rate = 1 / exchange_rate

            numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
            one = round(numbers.index(1) * exchange_rate, 3)
            two = round(numbers.index(2) * exchange_rate, 3)
            three = round(numbers.index(3) * exchange_rate, 3)
            four = round(numbers.index(4) * exchange_rate, 3)
            five = round(numbers.index(5) * exchange_rate, 3)
            six = round(numbers.index(6) * exchange_rate, 3)
            seven = round(numbers.index(7) * exchange_rate, 3)
            eight = round(numbers.index(8) * exchange_rate, 3)
            nine = round(numbers.index(9) * exchange_rate, 3)
            ten = round(numbers.index(10) * exchange_rate, 3)
            eleven = round(numbers.index(11) * exchange_rate, 3)
            twelve = round(numbers.index(12) * exchange_rate, 3)
            thirteen = round(numbers.index(13) * exchange_rate, 3)
            fourteen = round(numbers.index(14) * exchange_rate, 3)
            fifteen = round(numbers.index(15) * exchange_rate, 3)
            sixteen = round(numbers.index(16) * exchange_rate, 3)

            reverse_one = round(numbers.index(1) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_two = round(numbers.index(2) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_three = round(numbers.index(3) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_four = round(numbers.index(4) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_five = round(numbers.index(5) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_six = round(numbers.index(6) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_seven = round(numbers.index(7) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_eight = round(numbers.index(8) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_nine = round(numbers.index(9) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_ten = round(numbers.index(10) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_eleven = round(numbers.index(11) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_twelve = round(numbers.index(12) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_thirteen = round(numbers.index(13) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_fourteen = round(numbers.index(14) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_fifteen = round(numbers.index(15) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            reverse_sixteen = round(numbers.index(16) * reverse_exchange_rate, 3)
            return render_template("table.html", form=form, currency_1=currency_1,currency_2=currency_2, exchange_rate=exchange_rate, numbers=numbers, one=one, two=two,three=three,four=four,five=five,six=six,seven=seven,eight=eight,nine=nine,ten=ten,eleven=eleven,twelve=twelve,thirteen=thirteen,fourteen=fourteen,fifteen=fifteen,sixteen=sixteen,reverse_exchange_rate=reverse_exchange_rate,reverse_one=reverse_one,reverse_two=reverse_two,reverse_three=reverse_three,reverse_four=reverse_four,reverse_five=reverse_five,reverse_six=reverse_six,reverse_seven=reverse_seven,reverse_eight=reverse_eight, reverse_nine=reverse_nine, reverse_ten=reverse_ten,                        reverse_eleven=reverse_eleven,reverse_twelve=reverse_twelve,reverse_thirteen=reverse_thirteen,reverse_fourteen=reverse_fourteen,reverse_fifteen=reverse_fifteen, reverse_sixteen=reverse_sixteen)
        else:
            message = "There was an error. Please try again."
            return message
```

This is the table.html:

```
{% extends "layouts/main.html" %}

    {% block content %}

        <h1 style="text-align:center">Currency Exchange</h1>

                <div style="margin-right:250px">
                    <div style="margin-left:250px">
                        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;", class="u-full-width">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{{ currency_1 }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ currency_2 }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ currency_2 }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ currency_1 }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ one }} </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_one }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 2 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{two }} </td>
                                    <td> 2 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_two }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 3 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ three }} </td>
                                    <td> 3 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_three }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 4 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ four }} </td>
                                    <td> 4 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_four }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 5 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ five }} </td>
                                    <td> 5 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_five }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 6 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ six }} </td>
                                    <td> 6 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_six }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 7 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ seven }} </td>
                                    <td> 7 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_seven }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 8 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ eight }} </td>
                                    <td> 8</td>
                                    <td> {{reverse_eight }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 9 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ nine }} </td>
                                    <td> 9 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_nine }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 10 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ ten }} </td>
                                    <td> 10 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_ten }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 11 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ eleven }} </td>
                                    <td> 11 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_eleven }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 12 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ twelve }} </td>
                                    <td> 12 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_twelve }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 13 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ thirteen }} </td>
                                    <td> 13 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_thirteen }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 14 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ fourteen }} </td>
                                    <td> 14 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_fourteen }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 15 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ fifteen }} </td>
                                    <td> 15 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_fifteen }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 16 </td>
                                    <td class="border-right"> {{ sixteen }} </td>
                                    <td> 16 </td>
                                    <td> {{ reverse_sixteen }} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <a class = "button button-primary" href="/form">Change Currencies</a>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to shorten all of this down?

I have tried to make a for loop with a range(0,50) in the app.py although it goes through the whole loop and then sends the last number to table.html. Is there a way to send each individual number to table.html?

Is there a different solution?

Please remember that I have been coding for 3 weeks and there is probably a very easy solution that I haven't figured out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep learning and coding, but I would take smaller steps. Repetitions are usually handled with data sequences (like lists) and program loops (like for item is sequence). https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @VPfB says, it's probably worth investigating datastructures.  Here's how you might use some with your existing code.

First I'll define a static exchange rate for the example:

```
exchange_rate = 1.4
```

Then build a **dictionary** called `headers` which contains these values:

```
headers = {
    'currency_1': 'USD',
    'currency_2': 'CAD',
    'exchange_rate': exchange_rate,
    'reverse_exchange_rate': 1 / exchange_rate,
}
```

I've just manually assigned the strings `'USD'` and `'CAD'` here for demonstration, but obviously you'd grab these from your form.

Then for the numbers you could do something like:

```
data = [dict(num=n,
             normal =  round(n * headers['exchange_rate'], 3),
             reverse = round(n * headers['reverse_exchange_rate'], 3)
      ) for n in range(0, 16)]
```

This is using list comprehension.  The above is essentially the same as:

```
data = [] # an empty list
for n in range(0, 16):
    d = {} # an empty dict
    d['num'] = n
    d['normal'] = round(n * headers['exchange_rate'], 3)
    d['reverse'] = round(n * headers['reverse_exchange_rate'], 3)
    data.append(d) # add this dict to the list.
```

which could also be written as:

```
data = [] # an empty list
for n in range(0, 16):
    d = dict(num  = n,
             normal = round(n * headers['exchange_rate'], 3),
             reverse = round(n * headers['reverse_exchange_rate'], 3))
    data.append(d) # add this dict to the list.
```

`data` is now a **list of dictionaries**.

You can then pass all of this to your template:

```
return render_template('index.html', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Then in your template, build the header row manually, and have a Jinja for loop loop through the `data` list:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>  
      <th>{{ headers['currency_1'] }}</th>
      <th>{{ headers['currency_2'] }}</th>
      <th>{{ headers['currency_2'] }}</th>
      <th>{{ headers['currency_1'] }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
      <td> {{ row['num'] }} </td>
      <td class="border-right"> {{ row['normal'] }} </td>
      <td> {{ row['num'] }} </td>
      <td> {{ row['reverse'] }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This renders in the frontend, something like:

[image: sample table]

Comment: What does row do? In table.html?

Comment: @MaximO Notice that's inside the loop `{% for row in data %}`. Within that loop, `row` is each dictionary inside the list `data`.  Remember `data` is a list of dictionaries. And the syntax `row['num']` returns the value stored in the key `'num'` in the `row` dictionary (In *this* loop it would return the numbers 0 thru 15).

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have a question though. Could I replace row with a different word/letter/variable?

Comment: @MaximO Of course.  In the example in my last comment, `row` is available within that `for` loop, so if you change it you need to change the terminology in the `for` declaration, aswell as inside the loop itself.  Though best just to experiment, as you probably have done already.